# How to find stopping distance of a car?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration

I am trying to calculate the minimum stopping distance of a car once the brakes are applied. I know that $F = ma$, and the braking force is $F = \mu N = \mu m g$, so
$$a = \mu g.$$
Next, by applying the kinematics equation
$$v_f^2 - v_i^2 = 2 a x$$
I found
$$v^2 = 2 a d$$
where $a$ is the deceleration, $v$ is the initial velocity, and $d$ is the stopping distance. Then
$$d = \frac{v^2}{2a} = \frac{v^2}{2 \mu g}.$$
Is this reasoning right?

Comment: What are you trying to figure out?  Are you worried about skidding?

Comment: I just want to calculate the minimum stopping distance of a car.

Comment: That would be the max. deceleration without skidding, which you know.  So apply that to a formula you have.  What do you get?

Comment: The kwisatz haderach has improved your post.

Comment: for mu = .9 and g= 9.8 m/sec², I get a = -8.82m/sec², but the model I have made gives me a= -2.3m/sec². Trying to figure out what went wrong

Comment: What is your velocity?

Comment: 100kmph is the velocity at braking

Comment: I'd need to know more about the model.  What distance does it give?

Comment: distance i get is 167.74 meters. Whereas ideally using the mentioned formula i should get 43.74 meters.For calulation of 43.74, i used mu=.9, g=9.8, v=27.78m/sec²(100kmph)

Comment: Did you convert the units properly? (i.e the km/hr to m/s)?

Comment: 27.777 m/sec  => works out for the 43.74 meters result.

Comment: It's the diff. in acceleration.

Comment: mu in model corresponds to .235

Comment: yes, I am trying to figure this out, I know that using ABS system I am maintaining my mu at .9 while braking, so even when my mu is .9 why is my actual deceleration not equal to mu*g=.9*9.8= 8.82 m/sec².

Comment: If you are using ABS, then the deceleration is intermittent.  That's probably your problem.  If ABS has a duty cycle of about 25% (75% off) then that would give results similar to what you have.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braking_distance

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct.  They differ from your model (which uses ABS braking) however, because they don't take into account the duty cycle of the braking.  If this is added to your calculations, then the two results should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you're saying that the work done on the car in distance $d$ has to be equal to its kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$. Then, using $W = F d$:

$$
F d = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \\
m a d = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \\
d = \frac{v^2}{2 a}
$$

So, yes, this equation is correct. Your relation between the two forces is also correct. Since mass drops out, the coefficient of friction simply relates (vertical) acceleration due to gravity with (horizontal) acceleration due to friction. Assuming this is the acceleration the car is capable of throughout the process of stopping, we plug this in to get

$$
d = \frac{v^2}{2 \mu g}
$$

I can't address any differences between this and your model because I don't know what your model is.

Comment: so deceleration of car would be  a=mu*g

Comment: Given what you've given us, I believe that's right.

Comment: so assuming g=constant, the braking distance is only depended on mu, so if two vehicles with different weight brake at same v and same mu, will the stopping distance be the same for both the vehicles?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like it. The heavier vehicle has more kinetic energy, but with friction modeled as we are here this is offset by the fact that the mass also increases the acceleration by increasing the force.

Answer (score -1):

When you're using the equation F=ma, the F is ALWAYS the total/resultant/net/unbalanced force, NOT one of the individual forces. It describes the effect (the acceleration) that happens due to the cause (the total force on an object). Here you happen to be right because (at least horizontally) there is only one force, the frictional force, so you should get a = mu*g, which is a constant, so the "SUVAT" equations for constant acceleration can be used.